# Only show texts, input boxes on hover

Tags: html, css

hey guys i need help i have this stylesheet and inside this is the admin div...its currently in 20px in width and 50px in height and when hovered by mouse pointer it goes larger..what i would like to happen is that when i hover my mouse pointer there as it expand the texts and input boxes then shows....
currently even my texts is inside this div.. the texts are still overlapping.. need help..

ps: im putting my login input boxes there..

html

```
    <div id="admin">
        <p>Admin</p>
        <p> 
        <input type="text">
        </p>
    </div>
```

css

```
     #admin{
width: 20px;
height: 50px;
color: white;
background-color: #000080;
position: absolute;
bottom: 10px;
-webkit-transition:width 2s;
    transition:width 2s;
     }
     #admin:hover{
width: 500px;
visibility: visible;
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the desired effect: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gNku/)** ?

```
<div id="admin">
    <p>Admin
        <input type="text"/>
    </p>
</div>

#admin {
   overflow:hidden;
   width: 20px;
   height: 50px;
   color: white;
   background-color: #000080;
   position: absolute;
   bottom: 10px;
   -webkit-transition:width 2s;
   transition:width 2s;
 }
 #admin p {
   white-space:nowrap;
 }
 #admin:hover {
   width: 500px;
   visibility: visible;
 }
```

Comment: excuse me but i added another input field but it goes on the bottom of the first 1.. how can i align it the same as the username or admin input field?

Comment: Do you want them all to be on the same line? If so, [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7gNku/1/)

Answer (score 0):

`overflow-y:hidden;` 
or 
`overflow:hidden`

Is that what you looking for? That will prevent any text from appearing outside the parent element.